# How to get a URL in response of a POST request that navigates to GET request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, rest

I'm working on a project in which I'm creating (POST) a book. Once the book is created, a unique bookId is generated and the response looks something like this:

```
{
    "bookId":"123pqr",
    "author":"Abc",
    "title": "Book1"
}
```

I have one GET request which basically fetches the book details using bookId - http://localhost:port/{bookId}.

I'm trying to get this above URL whenever I create a book so that my response should look like this:

```
{
    "bookId":"123pqr",
    "author":"Abc",
    "title": "Book1"
    "url": "http://localhost:port/{bookId}"
}
```

So that if a user clicks on the URL, the user should be navigated to a GET request http://localhost:port/{bookId}. I think I can just hardcode a string "http://localhost:port/" and then append bookId to it and provide the same in response. However, I'm not sure how to set the request type as GET when the URL is clicked. Also, is there a better way to avoid harcoding? Could someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you got the wrong understanding of what are you doing. The requests are typically executed by the browser from the user perspective, so doing the GET has nothing to do with SpringBoot, this is something you have to do with JS or whatever you are using on the client side. Hardcoding is never a good option, you can get the server:port via app properties.

Comment: I'm using Postman to hit my REST endpoints. I have seen projects where the response from the POST request has a link along with other fields and when that link is clicked, it navigates to GET request of the same item just created.

Comment: Then the configuration goes thru postman. Your response from your service is quite right by now. You have to configure postman to do a GET request when click a link.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify anything to consider a URL as a GET.

This is natively part of every browser.

However, you could think a bit further and use **HATEOAS** which specifies the kind of relationship for a specific `href`

Your response would look like the following where `self` is standardized to be a `GET` request since it's the retrieval of the resource

```json
{
    "bookId":"123pqr",
    "author":"Abc",
    "title": "Book1"
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:port/{bookId}"
        }
    }
}
```

More information can be found here

- [Spring HATEOAS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) which BTW can also help with building the URI and thus no need to hardcode `localhost` and `port` making your app dynamic enough

Comment: You're welcome @Anita, feel free to accept the answer as to communicate this question is solved